# How to change the formatting of VS Code with Prettier enabled?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

When I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, my code is automatically formatted to this:

```
< h1 > Title < /h1 >
```

where it all saves to the same line. But I want it to format like this:

```
< h1 >

Title 

< /h1 >
```

Where all three properties are saved to their own respective line. I prefer this because it makes it personally makes it better for me to read and edit my code.

How do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the way how this extension format your code! But you can keep this extension enabled and make HTML as an exception like this way:
create a `.prettierignore` file

```json
{
   "editor.defaultFormatter":"esbenq.prettier-vscode",
   "[HTML]":{
      "editor.defaultFormatter":"<another formatter>"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is super helpful :)